# TypeError: 'module' object is not callableが出ます

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

下の画像のようなエラーが出ます。
このエラーが出た理由がわかりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参照：Pythonで始める機械学習

Comment: [IPython.displayモジュールの中のdisplay関数](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

完全な名前で `IPython.display` と書いた時これはモジュール、つまり`IPython`という名前のパッケージに束縛されている`display`という名前のモジュールを指します。
完全な名前で `IPython.display.display` と書いた時これは関数、つまり`IPython.display`という名前のモジュールに束縛されている`display`という名前の関数を指します。

`from IPython import display`と書いたあと、displayという名前はIPython.displayというモジュールを指します。だから `display(...)` と呼び出すことはできません。
`from IPython.display import display`と書いたあと、displayという名前はIPython.display.displayという関数を指します。だから `display(...)` と呼び出すことができます。

どうでしょう?

Comment: 分かりました。有難うございます。

Answer (score 0):

`from IPython import display` を `from Python.display import display` にするとエラーが回避されました。`from ○○ import ○○` の場合モジュール名？だけでいいものと思っていましたし他のものはエラーはでなかったのにdisplayだけエラーが出たの‌​が何故かは分かりません。